# horizontal mouse wheel messages from windows raw input

Tags: c++, windows, raw-input

I've noticed there isn't a documented equivalent to WM_MOUSEHWHEEL for windows raw input, yet I am receiving WM_INPUT messages for horizontal wheel clicking. Before I embark on my journey to re-invent the wheel (stupid pun intended), has anyone already cataloged such messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, took about 5 minutes.

In the event that anyone comes looking for this, it seems that a `#define RI_MOUSE_HWHEEL 0x0800` solves the problem. Testing for this flag is the same as with `RI_MOUSE_WHEEL`. The delta is in the usButtonData: positive for right, negative for left.